# Looping fscanf causing additional loops (C language)

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I am facing problems looping a fscanf. As in the code below (focus on the part where the while loop starts), I am looping the fscanf until it reached EOF. As you can see from the 2nd part below, the .txt file to fscanf from has only 6 strings,so the fscanf should only loop 6 times and then it reaches EOF. However, as you can see from the program output (2nd part belowe), the fscanf is looped 7 times. Since my program displays the missilenames in reverse order, I assume the while loop looped 1 additional time at the end, resulting at the blank line output on the first line of 3rd picture.

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem pls?

**C CODE**

```
while(fscanf(readmissiles,"\n %s \n",missilename)!=EOF)
        {
            missilename=malloc(20*sizeof(char));
            insertvalue(LL,missilename);
            missilenum++;
        }
```

**TEXT FILE TO FSCANF FROM**

single

splash

single

V-Line

h-line

Single

**OUTPUT/DISPLAY**

/*there is a blank line displayed before the Single*/

Single

h-line

V-Line

single

splash

single

7

Comment: With `missilename=malloc(20*sizeof(char));` you overwrite the pointer value, possibly loosing the results of `scanf`.

Comment: I solved the problem. I used fgetc(..)!=EOF as the loop condition and put my fscanf(..)into the loop beneath the malloc. At the beginning of the loop, i used fseek(..,-1,SEEK_CUR)to move the current back one space since it was moved by fgetc during the loop condition checking. I got the output I desired. Is this the optimal way or is there another more simplier way because mine sounds stupid.

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` returns the number of elements scanned or `EOF` in case of error or end of file is reached before it could match anything. On the last loop `fscanf` returns 0 - it did not scan the element but it scanned `\n`, so it returns `0`. Do:

```
while(fscanf(readmissiles, "%s", missilename) == 1)
```

Loop until there is one element scanned.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clarification. However, I tried out the code fscanf(...)==1 and the console output gave me 0, which I believe is because something caused my loop to never begin, thus only outputting the missilenum (orginally declared 0 before increment in every loop).